# MySQL - Request to count periodically with accumulation

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I never found an answer to this.

I have a User table which is as follows :

```
| id | pseudo      | inscription date |
|----|-------------|------------------|
| 1  | johndoe     | 01/01/1970       |
| 2  | janeyes     | 02/01/1970       |
| 3  | thirdpseudo | 05/01/1970       |
```

And I am searching for a query to do statistics of accumulation. I would like to retrieve, day by day, the number of users registered.

I made a query that retrieves only for the registering days, but I don't find how to accumulate every days...

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d/%m/%Y") AS 'Day', COUNT(*) AS 'Number of registered users'
FROM User
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

This query outputs :

```
| date       | number of registered users |
| ---------- | -------------------------- |
| 01/01/1970 | 1                          |
| 02/01/1970 | 1                          |
| 05/01/1970 | 1                          |
```

The output I would like for this example is :

```
| date       | number of registered users |
| ---------- | -------------------------- |
| 01/01/1970 | 1                          |
| 02/01/1970 | 2                          |
| 03/01/1970 | 2                          |
| 04/01/1970 | 2                          |
| 05/01/1970 | 3                          |
| 06/01/1970 | 3                          |
```

Comment: Generate calendar table. Join your table by calendar date is not less than registering date. Aggregate by calendar date and count. Or use correlated subquery in the output list for aggregating.

Comment: Hi Martin. What do you exactly expect? number of registered users per day, if there is no users then 0. or do you want to get running total for registered users in some date range? in other words, sum per day but with sum from previous days?

Comment: @Akina Ok, that's a good idea ! I'll be thinking of it

Comment: @StanislavBalia Hello ! Actually, I am searching to generate a graph where we cann see, for each day, the number of people who were registered in the platform. Like if I had done a "count" of the users table each day and registered it in an other table, but I didn't made this so I want to recreate the data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to generate some dates data defined as range of dates. Then join all users available to these dates and count how many users were registered during such days.

Here is the code:

```
-- creating simple table
create table Users
(
    id int not null,
    pseudo varchar(15),
    date date
);

-- adding some data
insert into Users
values 
(1,'jonh','1970-01-01'),
(2,'doe','1970-01-02'),
(3,'janeyes','1970-01-02'),
(4,'third','1970-01-03'),
(5,'pseudo','1970-01-03'),
(6,'title','1970-01-04'),
(7,'somename','1970-01-04'),
(8,'anothername','1970-01-04');

-- defines the start date and the end date
set @startDate = '1970-01-01';
set @endDate = '1970-02-01';

-- recursively geneterates all dates within the range
with RECURSIVE dateRange (Date) as 
(
    select @startDate as Date
    union ALL
    select DATE_ADD(Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    from dateRange
    where Date < @endDate
)
-- using SUM() over () would result in running total starting 
-- from 1, it would count next day + all previous days
select Date, Sum(RegisteredUsersCount) over(order by RegisteredUsersCount asc
                                            rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as RegisteredUsersCount
from 
(
  -- left join will join all users, if there is no users that correspond to the date of join, then it would be 0 for that date.
  select dr.Date, Count(u.id) as RegisteredUsersCount
  from dateRange as dr
  left join Users as u
  on dr.Date = u.date
  group by dr.Date
) as t
order by Date asc;
```

And working example to test: [SQLize Online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/7a6f36b8a8d4e3b9056f58cf8d655047/)

Comment: Interesting, but this shows the users registered during the day. Here, I have "3" as result in the array when I look at the key 1970-01-04. I would have "8" because if we have looked to the table at this day, we would have found 8 users in the DB (the 3 created the 1970-01-04 and the 5 created before ;))

Comment: @MartinS., edited my answer as well as link to SQLIze, check it. Now it works as expected, counting current day + count from previous days. So you would get "8" for 1970-01-04, "5" for 1970-01-03 and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, it seems nice ! I'll do it now on my real table. Also thanks for the explanations :)